# How to make a unique key/value JSON file from a CSV column with comma delimited rows (in Python)

Tags: python

I have a CSV file that consists of a column with comma delimted values for each row:
Example:

```
Area,Contact Number,Contact,Service,Category
"Bonanza, Gordondale, Knopcik, Pouce Coupe, Progress, Valhalla North, Valhalla South, Wapiti",1-866-694-9111,911 Industrial Response,Ambulance Oilfield,Emergency Services
"Alderson, Astotin, Bonanza, Crossfield, Gordondale, Hayter, Knopcik, Pouce Coupe, Progress, Provost Czar Metiskow, Redwater, Valhalla North, Valhalla South, Viking Consort Esther Hamilton Lake, Wapiti",1-800-661-3822,Alberta Central Air (ACA) - Medivac Flight Services,Air Ambulance,Emergency Services
```

How can I convert ONLY THE AREA COLUMN OF THE CSV to a JSON with **unique key:value** pairs? Example desired output:

```
{
    "Bonanza": "Bonanza",
    "Gordondale": "Gordondale",
    "Pouce Coupe": "Pouce Coupe",
    "Progress": "Progress",
    "Valhalla North": "Valhalla North",
    "Valhalla Sorth": "Valhalla Sorth",
    "Wapiti": "Wapiti",
    "Knopcik": "Knopcik"
}
```

Comment: is `Column 1 - Row 1:` actually part of the file?

Comment: No.  I am adding it there as a reference.  Let me update so its more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the structure of your file, maybe it's easier to load into pandas and do it from there.

```
import pandas as pd
set_values = pd.read_csv('untitled1.txt').Area.str.split(',').explode().str.strip().unique().tolist()
dict(zip(set_values,set_values))
```

Output

```
{'Bonanza': 'Bonanza',
 'Gordondale': 'Gordondale',
 'Knopcik': 'Knopcik',
 'Pouce Coupe': 'Pouce Coupe',
 'Progress': 'Progress',
 'Valhalla North': 'Valhalla North',
 'Valhalla South': 'Valhalla South',
 'Wapiti': 'Wapiti',
 'Alderson': 'Alderson',
 'Astotin': 'Astotin',
 'Crossfield': 'Crossfield',
 'Hayter': 'Hayter',
 'Provost Czar Metiskow': 'Provost Czar Metiskow',
 'Redwater': 'Redwater',
 'Viking Consort Esther Hamilton Lake': 'Viking Consort Esther Hamilton Lake'}
```

Comment: I apologize Chris I should have been more clean in my original post.  I have updated the original posting.  Can you help further explain how to do this using the updated posting?

Comment: It seems to be giving only unique characters, not words.  I tried the above, but I am getting the following:{
    "G": "G",
    "n": "n",
    "z": "z",
    "C": "C",
    "t": "t",
    "S": "S",
    ",": ",",
    "P": "P",
    "d": "d"
}.

Comment: Can someone help?

Comment: What do I do if I wanted to run this for another column with a space in the name, say Contact Number?